# To find the equation of the plane.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, analysis

Let $a= (3,1,-2), v_1 = (1,-1,2),v_2=(1,0,-1)$ and consider the set $V = \{ a+c_1v_1+c_2v_2, c_1,c_2 \in \Bbb{R}\}$. Note that the set is a plane. We have to find the equation of the plane.

Let $u_1 = v_1-a = (-2,-2,4)$ and $u_2 = v_2 -a= (-2,-1,1)$. Now $u_1 \times u_2 = (2,-6,-2)$ is the normal to the plane. Thus the equation of plane passing through $a= (3,1,-2)$ and normal to $(2,-6,-2)$ is given by:

$$2(x-3)-6(y-1)-2(z+2) = 0 \implies x-3y-z-2=0$$

Is the solution to the problem correct?

Comment: Do you mean $u_1=a\times v_1?$ Because $av_1$ doesn’t make sense.

Comment: $u_1 = v_1 - a$ as the vector @ThomasAndrews

Comment: $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ are vectors in the plane so the normal vector to the plane is $\vec{v_1} \times \vec{v_2}$. The vector $\vec{u_1}=\vec{v_1}-\vec{a}$ is not in the plane (assuming $\vec{a}$ is the position vector).

Comment: You only need $v_1\times v_2$ to get the orthonormal vector for the plane.

Comment: Do you mean $$\vec{x}=\vec{a}+s\vec{v_1}+t\vec{v_2}$$

Comment: Your equation isn’t satisfied by $a-v_2=(2,1,-1).$

Comment: You can check your own work: expand $a+c_1v_1+c_2v_2$ and plug the result it into the equation that you’ve come up with.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes

Answer (score 1):

What you derived is the plane containing the three given points, which is not what the question asks.

From the set defined by

$$V = \{ a+c_1v_1+c_2v_2 \}$$

you have, for each coordinate,

$$x=3+c_1+c_2$$
$$y=1-c_1$$
$$z=-2+2c_1-c_2$$

Eliminate $c_1$ and $c_2$ to obtain the plane

$$x+3y+z-4=0$$

This is the plane containing the point $a$ and parallel to that formed by the vectors $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$.